# Firebase Unity Auth not working

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Email/Password Authentication into my app but whenever I run my app (In Editor or on the phone) nothing happens (Nothing in Forebase console and also nothing is Unity console). I made sure that the values are passed correctly and I'm starting to feel that I failed something really basic.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RegisterOrSignInButtonClicked : MonoBehaviour {

    public string buttonMode;
    public Text Email;
    public Text password;
    public Text topText;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;


    void Start () {
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        auth.StateChanged += Auth_StateChanged;
        Auth_StateChanged (this, null);
    }

    void Auth_StateChanged (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (auth.CurrentUser != user) {
            user = auth.CurrentUser;
        }
        if (user == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!user.IsEmailVerified ) {
            user.SendEmailVerificationAsync ();
        }
        if (auth.CurrentUser != null) { 
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("ClickMenuScene");
        }
    }


    public void buttonClicked(){
        topText.text = Email.text.ToString();
        if(buttonMode.Equals("Register")){
            auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email.text.ToString(), password.text.ToString()).ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsCanceled) {
                    Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted) {
                    Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }

                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            });
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Put Debug.Log in the `buttonClicked` and see if that's even getting called

Comment: yeah it gets called, checked it.

Comment: Put Debug Log in `if(buttonMode.Equals("Register"))` too

Comment: Ok. Now, put another one inside `if(buttonMode.Equals("Register"))`

Comment: also gets called

Comment: How about another right after the line `auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email.text.ToString(), password.text.ToString()).ContinueWith(task => {` and print out the `task` to see what it has, if you don't see the debug statements, probably the start() is not called, because the script instance is not enabled, change `void start()` to `void awake()` and try.again

Comment: I think it might be because my Resolution keeps failing.

Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:4.2.0@aar
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:4.2.0@aar

Comment: Is all this code necessary to reproduce the problem? For example, if you remove the text fields and inputs and hard code those, does it still occur? Which specific line is it ending on? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).